# convert Timestamps to month-year

Tags: python, pandas

How do I convert the timestamps to month-year.i.e. 9/5/2019  to Sep-2019.
I tried this but I'm getting array. here is what i did.

pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Timestamp']).year

pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Timestamp']).date

In this case I get arrays that I can append them together. But I'm looking for more efficient and also get letter month like 'Sep' instead of 9.

Thanks

Comment: Please be clear in what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Show what you have tried and what you got.

Answer (score 2):

The method I use for formatting datetimes in my application uses the `datetime.datetime` module.
I use the `datetime.strftime()` function to get a formatted string from a `datetime` object

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime.now()
pretty_date = datetime.strftime(timestamp, '%d/%b/%y')
print(pretty_date)
```

Output:

```
18/Nov/19
```

The exact same method can be used for `date` objects.

Code:

```
from datetime import date

timestamp = date.today()
pretty_date = date.strftime(timestamp, '%d/%b/%y')
print(pretty_date)
```

Output:

```
18/Nov/19
```

For a list of format codes for the `strptime` and `strftime` functions, they can be found in the [python docs for datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your datetime format your using like this:

```
$ cat newdate.csv 
Name,Date
Will,9/5/2019
Bill,11/5/2019

df=pd.read_csv('newdate.csv')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%b-%Y') 

#In [323]: df                                                                                                                                                                                           
#Out[323]: 
#   Name      Date
#0  Will  Sep-2019
#1  Bill  Nov-2019
```

You may be able to use this next line directly if you update the column name

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

so if you date column has a name other than 'Date', just change it to your column name